# Google Sheet - Hide cell value if not authorize

Tags: google-sheets

I had a GSheet file with a vote system like this 

`|user1|1|4|6|
|user2|5|4|1|
|user3|2|4|4|
...`

Actually, each user can only edit his line with cell authorization. We want to "hide" cells of other user, is this possible ??

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome. The question is too broad. Please describe briefly what you mean by "hide" (is this like using a filter/filter view, right clic the row hand choose hide row, etc.) and add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can easily hide a column or a row either changing the size to 0 or groupping it and then hide it. To do something like hiding all users save for user 2 (for instance) you'd have to build a script that first identifies the user and then hide all rows and then show the row where that user is. It's not simple and easy.

On the other hand you could (should) have a database tab, hidden and with protection so nobody except you and editors can see, and then another tab where you dropdown select the user and formulas that show the data from the user selected. If you wanted to prevent people from choosing other users but themselves you are complicating things, this would recquire user validation, something that is more complex and I don't know if google sheets can achieve.